# JBoss-6.1.0.Final ( Community Edition) - javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

We are using `jboss-6.1.0.Final` (Community Edition) for running a stock market related application (EJB2.1 application/MDB).

Basically our environment is having two application servers (Primary Server and Secondary Server) and Oracle (version 10, Standard Edition) as database.
Both Primary and Secondary servers are collected New Order Request's and  sent to Stock Exchange through JBoss Hornet Queue.

Only Primary is responsible for picking/processing the execution reports for above mentioned new Order Request's by looking a JBoss Hornet Queue. Some days we have noticed some execution reports are not processed (1 or 2 out of around 1000), when processing those execution reports through Primary Server.
Exception details are as below.
Here are the exception details:

```
11:39:40,378 WARN  [jta] ARJUNA-16037 Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource < formatId=131076, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=28, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a8cb27:126a:56ab4746:ac846, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a8cb27:126a:56ab4746:ac84b, eis_name=unknown eis name >
11:39:40,410 INFO  [jta] ARJUNA-16013 Rolling back < 131076, 29, 28, 0000000000-1-1-64-88-5339001810686-8571700177-83490000000000-1-1-64-88-5339001810686-8571700177-78 >
11:39:41,425 WARN  [jta] ARJUNA-16036 commit on < formatId=131076, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=28, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a8cb27:126a:56ab4746:1107ad, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a8cb27:126a:56ab4746:1107b2, eis_name=unknown eis name > (org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@55e02042) failed with exception $XAException.XAER_NOTA: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1040) [:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.commit(OracleXAResource.java:573) [:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.commit(XAManagedConnection.java:279) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelCommit(XAResourceRecord.java:442) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doCommit(BasicAction.java:2789) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doCommit(BasicAction.java:2705) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.phase2Commit(BasicAction.java:1788) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1481) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:99) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:119) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.endTransaction(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:434) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.finish(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.after(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:213) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.invoke(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:124) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientMethodInterceptor.invoke(ClientMethodInterceptor.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at $Proxy493.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)  at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:287) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:866) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$100(ClientConsumerImpl.java:44) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:983) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]

11:39:41,457 WARN  [HornetQMessageHandler] Unable to call after delivery: javax.resource.ResourceException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.after(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:217) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.invoke(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:124) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientMethodInterceptor.invoke(ClientMethodInterceptor.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at $Proxy493.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)  at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:287) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:866) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$100(ClientConsumerImpl.java:44) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:983) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:119) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.endTransaction(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:434) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.finish(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.inflow.MessageEndpointInterceptor.after(MessageEndpointInterceptor.java:213) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 12 more
```